# Getting admin privileges on a mac with almost no access

Tags: macbook-pro, administrator

I have a MacBook Air that has single use mode and terminal blocked off and I want to get admin access because with out it I can do absolutely nothing. I thought maybe I could get into it using another computer or something but I have no clue. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I am on the brink of giving up so if anyone has any ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: Is it yours? Did you set it up originally?

Comment: no i didnt...sadly

Comment: Does your Mac support Target Disk Mode?

Comment: @patrix Firmware password that restricts single user mode also restricts target disk mode and selecting netboot / alternate OS to bring a new admin account to bear. Perhaps the OP can explain how / why single user mode is blocked in case it's not the logical cause of a Firmware password.

Answer (score 3):

There are three avenues:

- get the firmware password or bypass that
- socially engineer the person or team that locked you out (try convincing them you have a decent need and can be trusted before you consider trying to blatantly deceive them)
- hope the os or third party software is unpatched and there is a known privilege escalation vulnerability you can exploit. (Assuming you can’t get the NSA or similar to help you)

In short, there is no easy way since you’re up against Apple engineering and trying to defeat the security of the system.

Bypassing firmware: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203409